# Error mesages after uninstall samsung scloud and youtube

Tags: samsung, root-access, uninstallation, system-apps, bloatware

After uninstalling Samsung bloatware (*) (using root), I am receiving the errors "Unfortunately com.samsung.android.scloud has stopped"
and "Unfortunately com.google.android.youtube has stopped" even if what an doing has no relation with youtube.

Every time I try to use the camera I receive many scloud error messages.why?
Is Samsung connecting to their cloud server even when this function is not used?
Should I remove(as root) the other system Samsung apps (S.Link, S. Print, S. push,...)?
What is trying to launch these deleted apps?
Is the any startup/triggers list from where these apps can be launched?

(*)(If not bloatware, at least for me they are non desired apps and installed as system apps).

Comment: How did you remove youtube? Most likely you have auto updates enabled in the play store. So it keeps trying to update youtube. Also deleting a system app general just deletes from from the user i.e user 0. Lastly a copy of youtube is within the cache. That why when you factory reset the system apps come back.

Comment: I have no autoupdate. BTW in my phone youtube was a system app, but using ES explorer and root access I managed to remove it. At the moment  I got rid of error message after enter in Play and yes Play was thinking that I had youtube installed, so I click on "update". But I still want to remove completely and then install as a user app. Regarding samsung cloud, I still have error message, and i cannot find this app to install as user

Comment: Samsung has their own pre-installed app updating service with Galaxy Apps. Samsungs backup and sync just about everything involving their products. Turning off Sync will also help with the Samsung cloud errors. Interesting, I am just curious why do you want to change these system apps to user apps? To be honest not every system cannot be converted like this and still do what they do. System apps have special permissions in the manifest that user apps do not have access to. Your the apps and your device may lose some functionality by this move. Get the Scloud apk at sammobile or apkmirror.

Comment: I have no account at samsung or sync account. I don't want this special permissions for these non desired System apps. I hope to loss all these extra functionalities but without error messages ;)

Comment: Alright then, Sync is not an account but a process. Make sure you disable synchronization (sync) of content. 
 Settings/cloud & accounts/accounts/turn off the auto sync toggle. That will help with the cloud errors. You might also need to look in settings of the apps were the Samsung errors are thrown such as the camera. Turn off backup (cloud), make sure there is no sync option within the app.

Comment: @BoLawson, I downloaded and installed apks for samsung.cloud and Samsung Galaxy (com.sec.android.app.sns3). Now get rid of previous error messages but I have a new one "Unfortunately com.osp.app.signin has stopped"